# AWS s3 image upload from cocoa OS X application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, amazon-s3

I could manage to upload a file to s3 using Rest api using "PUT" method.
I am setting "x-amz-acl" header as "public_read". But after upload when I try to make the object as public by clicking "Make Public" in aws site its giving access denied error.

**Error
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;**

***Bucket is having public access.***

How can I solve this issue.Need help.
Thanks in Advance

Code Used

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/ansu/Desktop/TEst3.png"  options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"Data read from %@ with error: %@", @"/Users/ansu/Desktop/TEst3.png", error);

// Mime type is now in fileResponse.MIMEType.
NSString * secretKey = SCERECT_KEY;
NSDate * date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"; //RFC2822-Format
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSString * contentType = @"Image/png";//fileResponse.MIMEType;
NSString * resource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@",BUCKET_NAME,PATH_TO_CREATE];
NSString * signn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@\n%@\n%@",@"PUT",contentType,dateString,resource];
NSString * signature = [self sha1For:signn withKey:secretKey];
signature = [signature stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSString * authAWS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"AWS ACCESS_KEY:%@",signature];

unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, md5Buffer);
NSData *md5data = [NSData dataWithBytes:md5Buffer length:sizeof(md5Buffer)];
NSString *md5Base64 = [md5data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

  // Build the un-authed request.
NSURL *url = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com"]    URLByAppendingPathComponent:
          PATH_TO_CREATE];
NSMutableURLRequest *originalRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
originalRequest.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
originalRequest.HTTPBody = data;
[originalRequest setValue:md5Base64 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-MD5 "];
[originalRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type "];
 [originalRequest setValue:authAWS forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization "];
 [originalRequest setValue:@"public-read" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-amz-acl"];

 [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:originalRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSInteger statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
NSLog(@"%@",httpResponse);
if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300){
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Fail");
}
}] resume];
```

Comment: Can you try NSURLConnection instead of NSURLSession and share the response in comment

Comment: Tried with nsurlconnection Got this as response

{ Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Length" =     (
        0
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 07 Feb 2020 09:35:51 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "\"b6695170f61d9f6e48abe3a07fdebe2e\""
    );
    Server =     (
        AmazonS3
    );
    "x-amz-id-2" =     (
        "KUC8sfFqUfqIsgVQ3wioF4fMq1xdt48oX2/im4n2UQV60bPihjY4+/H3+O3LzYPoD2RSQ6E0Yhg="
    );
    "x-amz-request-id" =     (
        5DC18987DC01798D
    );
    "x-amz-server-side-encryption" =     (
        AES256
    );
} }